# boost::regex linking issue in Xcode 4.5.2

Tags: c++, regex, boost, xcode4.5

I am sure this question has been asked in many different guises ( apologies in advance )-
I am using Xcode 4.5.2

Very simple does-nothing terminal application as follow...

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    boost::regex regday_pattern("\\");
    return 0;
}
```

Appreciate that regex in boost requires a library and not just a boost header. Being relatively new to xcode and the unix environment underneath I am a little confused as to how I need my setup so that I don't get the following linking error...

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::basic_regex

Any help on this issue will be gratefully appreciated - I have read several responses to similar questions and have had trouble mapping those to my situation.
TIA

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If you did, I and maybe others could benefit from the answer.

Comment: @TreverDixon see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting a linker error because you didn't actually build the Boost.Regex libraries.

Please follow the [**build instructions**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) from the Boost documentation:

> Issue the following commands in the shell (don't type $; that
>   represents the shell's prompt):

```
$ cd path/to/boost_1_53_0 
$ ./bootstrap.sh --help
```

> Select your
>   configuration options and invoke ./bootstrap.sh again without the
>   --help option. Unless you have write permission in your system's /usr/local/ directory, you'll probably want to at least use

```
$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=path/to/installation/prefix
```

> to install
>   somewhere else. Also, consider using the `--show-libraries` and
>   `--with-libraries=library-name-list` options to limit the long wait you'll experience if you build everything. Finally,

```
$ ./b2 install
```

> will leave Boost binaries in the `lib/` subdirectory of
>   your installation prefix. You will also find a copy of the Boost
>   headers in the `include/ subdirectory` of the installation prefix, so
>   you can henceforth use that directory as an `#include` path in place of
>   the Boost root directory.

Finally, make sure that you can build and run the [**Regex example**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library) from the Boost documentation.